# How to retrieve reportFolder.meta-xml files with the Access Type and ParentId attributes?

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, reporting, retrieve

One can retrieve reports/dashboards via sfdx or via package.xml easily but when trying to deploy them to another org, errors like 'report folder doesn't exist' are hit if the report/dashboard is in a custom report/dashboard folder.

You can SOQL the folders created but I cannot see how to retrieve the actual reportFolder/dashboardFolder meta-xml files; which are needed for a successful deployment?

Answer (score 0):

In your package.xml you have to include report folder name and report name as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <types>
                <members>MyFolder</members>
                <members>MyFolder/Report1</members>
                <members>MyFolder/Report2</members>
                <name>Report</name>
        </types>
</Package>
```

Please note `<members>MyFolder</members>`, this is the important part for you.
The same apply for dashboard folders and email folders.
If you want to retrieve just the folder metadata you can also use sfdx cmd:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Reportfolder:MyFolder
```

Comment: Thanks - I forgot about the sfdx way - it's confusing that the metadata type is Folder but the actual command uses Reportfolder. Also, my report folder has an access type of Public but when I retrieve it via sfdx, only the name attribute is populated. Also, if my report folder is a parent of another reprot folder, upon retrieval, the parentId is also blank. How can I retrieve those other attributes too? When I add them manually to the .xml file and try to deploy, an error is returned. How can I deploy a public report folder then without any post deploy steps? Thanks

Comment: For subfolder, just update your package.xml with <members>MyFolder/MySubFolder</members>. 
If you don't have any<folderShares> in your report folder metadata, it should be consider as public.

Comment: to retrieve subfolder through cli it's simply sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Reportfolder: MySubFolder

Comment: OK thanks but the output isn't what I expect because parentId attribute is not there. Also, even when the accessType is public (I can see that when I do a SOQL), when I retrieve it, there's no attribute to indicate that the reportFolder is public. This seems poorly documented.